How to turn off (filter out) Staging Ground questions
The guide for staging ground says it's available for

Users who want to review and offer guidance on newcomers’ posts

I take the 'want' to mean that it's an opt-in feature. But I can't find a way to turn it off.
Is there an option to turn it off or is it a mandatory thing?

Looks like this has been asked before, Allow excluding/including/only having Staging Ground posts in a Custom filter, but the answer is in the comments rather than an answer.

For Staging Ground questions shown in regular question lists
Concerning Staging Ground like these:


Go to your Stack Overflow profile settings

Disable "Show Staging Ground questions".



For the Staging Ground itself
There are two roles for Staging Ground: asker and reviewer.
You cannot opt out as being classified as asker for Staging Ground.
You can opt out as being reviewer by not visiting.

"Apparently SO doesn't like people getting a good answer quickly" That's not why, @HansKilian, it's to stop FGITW answers getting the "accepted" tick immediately and allow other users to contribute answer(s) before you chose a solution.

Like a lot of decisions on SO, that doesn't make much sense to me

It is actually one I agree with. FGITW answers can be quite poor. They often don't take the time to explain the solution and use the shortest amount of the text to answer the question asked and that's it; they have a higher likelihood of not being useful to future readers.

On Stack Overflow, you don't "get good answers quickly" by asking a question and having someone quickly answer it. That's not what a Q&A site is; it's what a help desk is, and we're not that. On Stack Overflow, you "get good answers quickly" by searching the existing Q&A and finding that it has already been asked and answered. The most important role of someone who asks a question is to enable the latter experience for everyone else.

Please think back to the case that the site founders made for the idea behind Stack Overflow in the first place. Programmers were frustrated with the experience provided by traditional discussion forums, because when you search them you maybe get an answer to someone else's question, after scanning through all the back and forth to clarify what the question is, and maybe disentangling it from the concerns of random third parties posting their "me too"s. The point of Stack Overflow is that we cut out the noise, force the clarification up front, and make the question be everyone's question.

Perhaps Stack Overflow should be turned off for like a good month. Give people an insight again into what they'd be missing. The idea of having actual usable reference material is so good. So good. And it is ruined so fast by prioritising your own needs first and trivializing the needs of others in the process.

The description of the option is backwards: it's a "Show" option but the description says that content will not be shown.

@khelwood it will no longer be shown when you flip the switch. It's currently set to "on", so it's showing them. Therefore if you flip it to the "off" position, then it will not show the content. The text is accurate. However, it doesn't change once you do flip it - it only covers the default state of the toggle. Presumably once you read it, you would know what the toggle controls, so no need for the description to be dynamic. Or it's just made dynamic yet. It's still early release of SG.

It doesn't make sense that the description require you to know and remember the default state of the toggle. All the other options describe the effect when the switch is on. It's just a badly thought out description.
